# React hook useState not setting correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am making a modal, which receives an obj(name and qty) from props and should display in input fields

```
export default function EditModal(props) {
  const { isVisible, onToggleModal, itemToBeEdited } = props;
  const obj = itemToBeEdited[0];

  const [ingredientName, setIngredientName] = useState(obj && obj.name);
  const [ingredientQty, setIngredientQty] = useState(obj && obj.qty);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIngredientName(obj && obj.name);
    setIngredientQty(obj && obj.qty);
  }, [itemToBeEdited]);
```

the above is how have my hooks set up. It is displaying the default value correctly now, but I know the setter methods are not being used correctly ... problem is that itemTobeEdited is undefined at first

and here is my text inputs

```
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              value={ingredientName}
              // onChangeText={}
            />
            <Text>Qty:</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              value={ingredientQty}
              // onChangeText={}
            />
```

any suggestions to what I should try ? 
Thank you !

Comment: Where is the `itemToBeEdited` defined in your code and why it's being used in the dependency array if it's not being used inside the `useEffect` itself? It looks like `obj` should be in the dependency array rather than `itemToBeEdited`.

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof itemToBeEdited === "object") {
      setIngredientName(itemToBeEdited.name);
      setIngredientQty(itemToBeEdited.qty);
    }
  }, [itemToBeEdited]);`
after changing `itemToBeEdited` from an array to an obj and like you said, use it in both the dep array and useEffect. now it works ! thank you 